# Delphi 6 command line compile: NO DCU’s

Tags: delphi, dcu

When using dcc32 against the .dpr file it produces a dll but no dcu’s.

The project level .cfg is using the –N switch to set the path but nothing is in the directory specified.  It must see the .cfg as the –E switch is working.

I tried to use brcc32/brc32 against the .dpr file before a call dcc32 but either one gives me the Error projectName.dpr 3 1: Expecting END?

I need the dcu’s from project1 for project2 which when I run the dcc32 against the .dpr it errors stating it can’t find the missing dcu’s from project1 for project2.

What steps, clc/utility need to be run to produce the dcu files?
Running on XP with Delphi 6 installed.
DCC32 v14
BRC32 v5.4

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it is ignoring the -N switch because it doesn't have one? As far as I know the switch to specify where the dcu's should go is the -N0 switch. (Letter N, digit zero).

Answer (score 1):

dcc32 --help is your friend here. In particular:

```
-N0<path> = unit .dcu output directory
```

(Note that D6 *does not* show this switch. D7 and more recent versions do.)

You do have to make sure that you include all necessary unit dependencies through the -U flag, resource dependencies through the -R flag, and so on. For instance:

```
dcc32 -B -CC -Q -E.\bin -IC:\home\work\Indy;C:\home\work\dUnit\src -LE.\bin -N0.\build -O"C:\home\work\Indy;C:\home\work\dUnit\src" -U"C:\home\work\Indy;C:\home\work\dUnit\src" -R"C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi6\source\Indy;C:\Program Files\Borland\Delphi6\lib" SIP.dpr
```

EDIT: It doesn't help that `dcc32 --help` does NOT tell you about the -N0 switch. I found this out the hard way, and it was only on the advice of my boss (Guido Gybels) that I managed to get things working.

Comment: If `dcc32 --help` doesn't tell you about -N0, then what is the meaning of the first two lines of your answer?

Comment: d7's and d2006's dcc32 both show -N0. But I wanted to direct the poster to what _should_ be the first source of info, while also pointing out the d6 pitfall.

Comment: Sorry Rob, I only just understood what you mean right now. Text amended.)

Comment: Well, in D6 the dcc32 help may not help (pun intended :-), but just looking through a cfg file with a dcu path set, should...